# Save file to a folder in the website in medium trust in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, hosting, medium-trust

In my website I save images to a folder(Photos) in code-behind by calling

`ImageUploadControl.PostedFile.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Photos/" + Name + ext));`

which throws an error `'Access not allowed'` in medium trust.
Any alternate to save images in medium trust? The folder needs to be publicly accessible as clients access these images without any authentication, so I cannot save it in App_Data(one fix to this problem)

*Website is hosted on hostgator shared plan. There is a limitation to how much I can ask for server configurations.

**EDIT:**

Yes its a access issue, as resolving the ~ tilda, virtual paths is not allowed. I hope anyone has a workaround for this problem.

Comment: Are you it's because it's medium trust? As you're using a native .NET control it sounds more like it's a permissions issue. Does the ASPNET user account have write access to that folder?

Comment: I tried the native .net file control and then the ajaxcontroltoolkit asyncfileupload control, problem with both.

Comment: I still think it's permissions then - If you hit a trust issue, then the app will not run as it can't load the required dll. This sounds like it's running but just doesn't have the rights to write to the directory. Can you do a `CreateTextFile()` operation in the same directory? If not, then the application doesn't have the right to write - Which you can set with the links in my answer below :)

Comment: Ok, having a look at them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you're using a native .NET control, I think it's more due to file system permissions than the trust of the environment. If you were using a 3rd party control I'd say then it's a trust issue.

Having a quick look at Hostgator they use cPanel, from there there's the file manager section, and in here if you go and select the `'Photos'` folder and select "Change Permissions", here make sure the folder has write access from the application.

### Edit

---

Support article here for setting *nix permissions: 
https://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-to-change-permissions-chmod-of-a-file

And:
https://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/my-script-needs-to-use-777-permissions

Comment: What's the usergroup or name of the usergroup whose permission needs to be changed?

Comment: That really depends on the hosting setup and what identity your application runs under - Normally it's something like ASPNET_USR, but could be application specific or your hosting account specific. You can always test by granting write permissions to "World" / "Everyone" - If this works, scale back the permissions to keep it secure. Sorry I can't be any more specific, but each host has a slightly different setup.

Answer (score 1):

OK, as it's a path issue:

https://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/server-path-absolute-path

Is it running ASP.NET on a *nix box? Or is it running on a Windows Server and IIS?

Also, I think you may need to revise your code in this instance:

```
string pathRoot = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Photos/");
ImageUploadControl.PostedFile.SaveAs(pathRoot + "/" + Name + ext);
```

It looks like your original code is trying to use `mapPath` with the non-existing file path included.

This may work if you must have it one line:

```
ImageUploadControl.PostedFile.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Photos/") + Name + ext);
```